# Migrate Windows phone 8 silverlight app to Windows 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

We already have a working and fully functional app working on store in Windows phone 8 silverlight framework. But keeping in Mind windows 10 will be releasing soon we want to be ready. We want to migrate the app to WinRT framework. What would be the best approach to do that.

I see there are a lot of changes at the framework level but still any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 1):

There's a [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452743.aspx) that targets the describes problem. The [most interesting part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn800286.aspx) is probably the mapping of silverlight namespaces to the corresponding WinRT namespaces (if available).

[Here](http://wmpoweruser.com/rudy-huyn-to-release-developer-tool-to-convert-silverlight-to-universal-app/) is an article about an app by Rudy Huyn to convert Silverlight application to universal apps. That could also be a great help.